# Meta, API Page Public Content Access, permission Review Issue

Tags: facebook

My meta app is in live mode, I have done the app review process. Every permissions are accepted. But for some reason, I don't think I need the permission. I have tried deleting the permission from permissions list and the app works in development mode. But for some reason becasue of this permission, my app can't go to permission. And I keep getting this error
[image: an error saying some of the permission are not reviwed yet]

I want to remove the permission as I believe our use case doesn't need this permission and was a mistake at my end. How can I remove it and how can I remove the permission and move on with normal users using it in live mode.

Here are all the permission my oauth login require as a JS array

```js
["pages_show_list",
  "instagram_content_publish",
  "pages_read_engagement",
  "business_management",
  "instagram_basic",
  "pages_manage_posts",
  "ads_management",
  "pages_read_user_content"]
```

I haven't used any SDKs but I have used APIs that uses combination of user_access_token and Page_access_token